# How to concatenate two field in single column in oracle SQLLDR control file?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

My raw text file like below (having two fields (ACC and INT))

ACC   INT

---

1160 1291

1160 1291

1160 1291

1160 1291

My table -> create table product(product_CODE number);

Control file ->
load data

infile 'E:\SQLLDR\product.txt' "str '\r\n'"

append into table product

fields

trailing nullcols
(

product_code position (1:9)

)

Requirement : Need product code without space like below

select * from product;

### PRODUCT_CODE

11601291

11601291

11601291

11601291

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the `REPLACE` function here considering it as a string as follows:

```
product_code position (1:9) "REPLACE(:PRODUCT_CODE,' ','')"
```

I have not tested it but you can leave a comment if you find any issue with this solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66774921/how-to-replace-sqlldr-values Can you check this

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE * 
append into table product
( ACC FILLER 
  INT FILLER 
  PRODUCT_CODE  VARCHAR "UPPER(:ACC || :INT)" 
)
```