# How to replace sqlldr values

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

My raw file like below

```
bbbb 1000 Open 1000 Dep  12/03/2010
dddd 1001 Open 2000 Loan 13/01/2019
eeee 1003 Dor  3000 Dep  11/04/1965
```

Sqlldr control file

```
load data
infile *
truncate into table Mytab
fields 
trailing nullcols
(
Name position (1:4),
Acc position(6:9),
Status Position(11:14),
Amt position(15:18),
type position(20:23),
Date position(24:33)
)

begin data
```

I need date column with hyphen(-) symbol not for slash(/) symbol.

```
12/03/2010 -- 12-03-2010
```

`Date position(24:33)` ---> What I have to mention here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you also provided `mytab` description. Because, "Date" column (whose name is invalid; it is reserved for datatype name. I renamed it to "Datum") should be of `date` datatype, while it seems you use `varchar2`. In either case, you'd use appropriate function, enclosed into double quotes. I used `replace` as it does what you asked for.

Here's an example:

Control file (yours is invalid as it doesn't follow data format; I fixed it):

```
load data
infile *
truncate into table Mytab
fields
trailing nullcols
(Name    position(1:4),
 Acc     position(6:9),
 Status  position(11:14),
 Amt     position(16:19),
 type    position(21:24),
 Datum   position(26:35) "replace(:datum, '/', '-')"
)

begindata
bbbb 1000 Open 1000 Dep  12/03/2010
dddd 1001 Open 2000 Loan 13/01/2019
eeee 1003 Dor  3000 Dep  11/04/1965
```

Loading session & result:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@xe control=test34.ctl log=test34.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sri O×u 24 07:54:46 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 3

SQL> select * from mytab;

NAME       ACC        STATUS     AMT        TYPE       DATUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
bbbb       1000       Open       1000       Dep        12-03-2010
dddd       1001       Open       2000       Loan       13-01-2019
eeee       1003       Dor        3000       Dep        11-04-1965

SQL>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66702660/sqlldr-loader-number-column-import     
      can you try this if possible

Comment: I just did; have a look.